# Get the firefox browser window handle from the extension's javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon

I'm writing a extension that needs to get the browser window handle. The extension will pass the window handle to the native c++ module.

How do I get the browser window handle from the extension's javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this might help a little :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Finding_Window_Handles

and maybe this

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2449775

Regards,